# multiple records key creation javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created an object something like this Object `{ 04:00-04:30=7 }` and I want to create something like this:

```
array = (
    ('10:00-10:30' => array('count' => 15), array('count' => 20)),
    ('10:30-11:00' => array('count' => 5))
    ('11:00-11:30' => array('count' => 8))
);
```

Comment: This is actually not javascript syntax, Do you want to create a multidimensional array in CoffeeScript?

Comment: i want to push mutiple values on same key

Comment: if at 0030-1000 i have 10 records then 0030-1000 i have 15 records so i want both records on same key

Comment: Are you using pure javascript? if not, please, bother to add a tag to your question in addition to `javascript`.

Comment: I am still not clear what you're trying to achieve regardless of the language chosen. In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpzkn3s1/) you can see how to define multiple (array of) values for one key in pure js. Let me know what you mean so that I can post full answer

Comment: how to do the same dynamically

Comment: Read my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to create an object, each key of which has a name which can't be an identifier (to tell the truth not the best idea unless there is no other way to store information) and the value of each key is an array:

```
var scheduleObject = {
    '0030-1000': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    '1000-1400': ['five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'],
    '1400-1500': []//empty array
};
scheduleObject['1400-1500'] = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve'];//modify value of existing key
scheduleObject['1500-1600'] = ['twenty', 'thirty'];//create a new key with value
```

The trick here is to get access to a key of your object. Normally you could do `scheduleObject.key`, but in your case the `key` contains dash `1500-1600`, so we use alternative javascript syntax `scheduleObject['key']` which is actually the same but you provide key name as a literal string and thus can overcome the troubled identifier.

Now most likely you want to iterate the keys of your schedule object and you can use `for ... in` operator

```
for(key in scheduleObject){
    if(scheduleObject.hasOwnProperty(key)){
       var schedule = scheduleObject[key];
// do something with each array 
    }
}
```